# GroovyConsole ActiveMQ error: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, noclassdeffounderror, groovy-console

I am trying to run a very simple ActiveMQ client script in GroovyConsole.  I've included activemq-all-5.5.0.jar and slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar through the Script > Add Jar to ClassPath menu.  I see org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy in the activemq jar, yet I am getting the exception below.

Here is the script:

```
import org.apache.activemq.*
import org.apache.activemq.command.*
import javax.jms.*
//
//
//

def connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616")
def connection =connectionFactory.createConnection()

def session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
def dest = new ActiveMQQueue("fieldrepresentative.updatelatlong.queue")
def producer = session.createProducer(dest)
connection.start()

def MapMessage message = session.createMapMessage()
message.setString("employeeId", "TS12345")
message.setString("latitude", "12345")
message.setString("longitude", "97874")

producer.send(message)

session.close()
connection.close()
```

The exception is:
    Jul 19, 2011 6:04:26 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize

```
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy

at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:88)

at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:131)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)

at MDBClient.run(MDBClient.groovy:8)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:266)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:517)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:172)

at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$run.call(Unknown Source)

at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure16.doCall(Console.groovy:910)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)

at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)

at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:885)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)

at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure16.doCall(Console.groovy)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)

at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)

at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:885)

at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)

at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:399)

at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:483)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy

at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:88)

at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.<init>(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:131)

at MDBClient.run(MDBClient.groovy:8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to have added to your classpath:-

- lib/optional/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar
- lib/optional/log4j-1.2.14.jar

I think because of this pre slf4j 1.6.0 'feature':- http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#libraries

Comment: Sorry to say that didn't help.