# JMS with ActiveMQ in Groovy - unable to resolve class ActiveMQConnectionFactory

Tags: groovy, activemq-classic

I am trying my first groovy JMS example: Also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755071/groovyconsole-activemq-error-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o). Did that but still Class not resolved.

```
@Grab(group='net.sf.gtools.jms', module='JmsCategory', version='0.2')
@Grab(group='org.apache.activemq',module = 'activemq-all', version='5.9.0')
@Grab(group="junit", module="junit", version="4.11")

class GroovyJMSExample {
    def sendMessage() {
        use(JmsCategory) {
            def jms = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory('tcp://localhost:61616')
            jms.connect { c ->
                c.queue("TEST-queue") { q ->
                    def msg = createTextMessage("test")
                    q.send(msg)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void main(String[] args) {
        sendMessage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example didn't work for me until I added `import net.sf.gtools.jms.JmsCategory` between the `@Grab`s and the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just need to add

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

After the `@Grab` lines, and before the `class GroovyJMSExample {` line?

Comment: Absolutely right. I assumed that Grab would locate the classes. Added import ....activemq.*. Moving on to next bug.

Answer (score 0):

with some (lots) of help from `#groovy` on freenode IRC:

```
@Grapes([
        @Grab(group = 'net.sf.gtools.jms', module = 'JmsCategory', version = '0.2'),
        @Grab(group = 'org.apache.activemq', module = 'activemq-all', version = '5.9.0'),
        @Grab(group = "junit", module = "junit", version = "4.11"),
        @Grab(group = 'net.sf.gtools.jms', module = 'JmsCategory', version = '0.2'),
        @Grab(group = 'org.apache.activemq', module = 'activemq-all', version = '5.9.0'),
        @Grab(group = "junit", module = "junit", version = "4.11"),
        @Grab(group = 'net.sf.gtools.jms', module = 'JmsCategory', version = '0.2'),
        @Grab(group = 'org.apache.activemq', module = 'activemq-all', version = '5.9.0'),
        @Grab(group = "junit", module = "junit", version = "4.11"),
        @Grab(group = 'net.sf.gtools.jms', module = 'JmsCategory', version = '0.2'),
        @Grab(group = 'org.apache.activemq', module = 'activemq-all', version = '5.9.0'),
        @Grab(group = "junit", module = "junit", version = "4.11")
])
import net.sf.gtools.jms.JmsCategory
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory

class GroovyJMSExample {
    def static sendMessage() {
        use(JmsCategory) {
            def jms = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory('tcp://localhost:61616')
            jms.connect { c ->
                c.queue("TEST-queue") { q ->
                    def msg = createTextMessage("test")
                    q.send(msg)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        sendMessage()
    }
}
```

Comment: This ActiveMQ producer works fine with the accompanying, remote, [consumer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.user/67083).